# How to change image from gray scale format into RGB format

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, rgb, grayscale

I was working on research about computer vision, but I got stuck when following a paper that said he could convert Grayscale image into RGB image using Python.

The first image would be like this.

[image: The original image]

The output will be like this.

[image: Image_2]

Is anyone could help me finish this problem?

Comment: I don't believe it.  The information is not there.  It's like the TV shows where they recreate  a completely sharp face from a blurry 32x32 thumbnail.

Comment: oh thank you, sorry I couldn't say the article wrong, this maybe me that easily take a conclusion

Comment: Apply a color map to your grayscale image. See cv2.applyColorMap() at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/d50/group__imgproc__colormap.html#gadf478a5e5ff49d8aa24e726ea6f65d15

Comment: Grayscale to color could simply mean taking the one gray channel and duplicating it 2 times so that one has 3 channels, one each for red, green and blue. This can be done with `cv2.merge([gray,gray,gray])` or with `cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)`

Comment: cite the paper?

Comment: @fmw42 thank you for your advice, I will rethinking about it

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thank you for your value to this question, oh yeah, I forgot to give citation to the paper. You can see the paper [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167404821003394)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, a grayscale image has just one channel (shades of gray), while, BGR (default color space in opencv, or BGRA if on mac)just like RGB has three channels (RED GREEN BLUE), you can convert it into grayscale using this formula:

> Y = 0.299 R + 0.587 G + 0.114 B

where `Y` is the one channel of grayscale image. But you can't do the vice versa. Grayscale is basically just different shades of gray. You can't do the reverse. In RGB/BGR a pixel looks like this `[R,G,B]` which is somewhat like an array, whereas in grayscale it is just a single value. We often consider `value < 100` as black in grayscale.

Image is often reprsented in form of an array (`np.array` in case of python), and the thing is, in most of the arrays, you can't modify the dimensions. Like `np.array` has an attribute called `shape` which tells us about the dimensions of the array, or in an image think of it like resolution. Shape of a grayscale image looks like this `(RESOLUTION-Y, RESOLUTION-X)`, which means it's a 2d matrix/array and one pixel is represented by a single value, whereas in RGB/BGR, the shape looks like this, `(RESOLUTION-Y, RESOLUTION-X, 3)`, so it's a 3d array, where 3 is the number of channels.